# Show splash screen on double clicking system tray icon

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have made an RCP application which starts by default on system startup. It has a login dialog which authenticates the user before creating workbench.

My application starts in system tray by default. Below is the code(I have only posted relevant code).

Application.java

```
public Object start(IApplicationContext context) {
   Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
   minimizeToTray(display,context);
}

private void minimizeToTray(Display display,IApplicationContext context){
  Shell displayShell = new Shell(display);
  URL imageURL =   Platform.getProduct().getDefiningBundle().getEntry(Platform.getProduct().getProperty("trayIcon"));
  Image image = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(imageURL).createImage();

  //Create Tray and add listener for double click
  trayItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            image.dispose();
            item.dispose();
            startLogin(); //Call login dialog and create workbench after authentication
            displayShell.dispose();
    }
   });


   //Close current splash screen.
   context.applicationRunning();       

   //Do-event loop
   while(!displayShell.isDisposed()){
        if(!display.readAndDispatch()){
            display.sleep();
        }
   }
}
```

When application starts, a splash screen is displayed. After adding application to system tray, I am closing the splash screen using `context.applicationRunning();` and waiting for user to double click the tray icon.

After the user double clicks the icon, I want to display the splash screen again.

Comment: You can't run the splash screen code again after startup - you will have to use an ordinary dialog containing similar data.

Comment: @greg-449 Is there any chance of using SplashHandlers to handle spash screen(show/hide). Sorry I am new to RCP.